# Размеры экранов для адаптивной верстки jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

эксперты!

Имеется следующий код для оптимизации адаптивной верстки:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("resize", resizeWindow);
    function resizeWindow(e){
      var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();

      // Если ширина меньше 600 px, используется таблица стилей для мобильного
      if(newWindowWidth < 600){
        $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "mobile.css"});
      } else if(newWindowWidth > 600){
        // Если ширина больше 600 px, используется таблица стилей для десктопа
        $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "style.css"});
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Необходимо сделать 2 версии сайта - под настольный ПК и для мобильного устройства.
В коде расчет на то, что устройство с шириной экрана менее 600px - мобильное. Однако не все моб устройства попадают в это уточнение.

Какие разрешения экранов используются в современных реалиях и как предпочтительнее использовать этот код для смены между декстоп/мобильной версией?